# Bind Label to a slider value in python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to programming, I read a few tutorials and a considerable amount of questions on this forum and now, I'm stuck.

I'm trying to have a label that states the value of a slider.  I'm using python 3.4.2 and kivy on a Raspberry pi 3.

I loosely (ok, not so loosely) based my code on this post: [Display kivy slider value as it changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820553/display-kivy-slider-value-as-it-changes)

Here's my (lightened) code:

```
def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(instance,value):
    FanSpeedLabel.text = str(value) 

class LayoutTest(App):
    def build(self):

       FanSpeed = Slider(min=0, max=4, step=1)

       FanSpeed.bind(value=OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange)

       FanSpeedLabel = Label(text= str(FanSpeed.value))
```

When I move the slider, the app crashes and I get this error:

```
 FanSpeedLabel.text = str(value)            
 NameError: global name 'FanSpeedLabel' is not defined
```

Where did I go wrong?  Any pointers would be appreciated!

P.S. when I get this to work, I will try to convert it into kivy language...  Because why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared **FanSpeedLabel** as a *local variable* and try to use it globally in **OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange**

To **start**, make **OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange** global

```
FanSpeedLabel = None

def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(instance,value):
    global FanSpeedLabel
    FanSpeedLabel.text = str(value) 

class LayoutTest(App):
    def build(self):
       global FanSpeedLabel
       FanSpeed = Slider(min=0, max=4, step=1)

       FanSpeed.bind(value=OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange)

       FanSpeedLabel = Label(text= str(FanSpeed.value))
```

*That said*, you should structure your code better using the kv lang and **don't use globals** :)

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try that for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your answer.  It got me reading again and discovering my error.  Newby error in Python I guess...  it was a matter of indentation!  I had tried to make my variable local without success...  because it was indented at the same level as the def build(self) variable it was supposed to be part of.

In conclusion, this fixed my error and I suppose, answers your advice of "not using globals":

```
class LayoutTest(App):
    def build(self):

    #-->| Just like that!  that little indentation!
        Def OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange(instance,value):
            FanSpeedLabel.text = str(value) 


   FanSpeed = Slider(min=0, max=4, step=1)

   FanSpeed.bind(value=OnFanSpeedSliderValueChange)

   FanSpeedLabel = Label(text= str(FanSpeed.value))
```

I hope this will help other newbs in my situation in the future!